# Importing data from an XLS File using ADO and Delphi

Tags: excel, delphi, ado, delphi-2010

I want to import some data from an Excel file ( xls ) by using `TADOConnection` and `TADOTable`.

I connect to file with no problem, but when i open `TADOTable` some fields have `ftFloat` datatype because their values in excel file are numeric, but their values are not a number!

I want all fields of `TADOTable` (columns of Excel file) to have `ftString` datatype.

I set the types of columms in Excel file to `Text` but no changes affected!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

I am guessing you have a majority of columns that may appear to be numeric, but also some that are pure text.

`ADO` effectively ignores the `column type` when importing an Excel. Instead, it guesses the column types, as stated in this [MSDN link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819/en-us):

> A Caution about Mixed Data Types
>
> As stated previously, ADO must guess at the data type for each column
>   in your Excel worksheet or range. (This is **not** affected by Excel cell
>   formatting settings.) A serious problem can arise if you have numeric
>   values mixed with text values in the same column. Both the Jet and the
>   ODBC Provider return the data of the majority type, but return NULL
>   (empty) values for the minority data type. If the two types are
>   equally mixed in the column, the provider chooses numeric over text.

One way to load **all** fields as strings is to use the `IMEX extended property` in your `connection string` like following:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";
```

Setting IMEX to 1 makes ADO treat all columns as text, as stated in following [ConnectionStrings page](http://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/treating-data-as-text/):

> Use this one [IMEX=1] when you want to treat all data in the file as text,
>   overriding Excels column type "General" to guess what type of data is
>   in the column.

You can find more information about the IMEX property in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102149/what-is-imex-in-the-oledb-connection-string).

**Update**: The field data type retrieved using this would be `ftWideString`.

Comment: thanks, if i use IMEX then i can`t write data in excel columns !;

Comment: "but return NULL (empty) values for the minority data type" Who designed this sh*t??? Just throwing away user data because it won't make the smart decision of taking the lowest common denominator (text) about data type.

Comment: @Mahmood_M, can you please elaborate on not being able to write data in excel columns? By the way, I forgot to mention the field data type would be `ftWideString`. Adding it now.