# SQL import from openrowset mixed type [keep leading 0, long ints and TEXT] correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, openrowset

I have a column in Excel I'm trying to import, and it includes codes like the following:

- 01166
- 1166
- 2354654765432
- xx132

I use IMEX=1 and everything imports as TEXT but when I assign the select to temporary table with nvarchar type, the codes with long numbers become incorrect:

```
1001051 becomes 1.00105e+006
```

I tried to cast to bigint, but this makes the code lose the leading 0 in `01166`

this is my current query:

```
INSERT INTO #XTEMP
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (CASE ISNUMERIC([item_code]) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(CAST([item_code] AS BIGINT) AS nvarchar) ELSE CAST([item_code] AS nvarchar) END)
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Database=C:\path\file.xls',
    'SELECT * FROM [sheet$]')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IMEX=1` allows reading mixed columns; it does not force data values to be text.
Looking at [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102149/what-is-imex-in-the-oledb-connection-string), you can see a possible workaround if you set `HDR=NO`, but that has its own complications.

If you can, the best thing to do is set the format of the column in the spreadsheet to Text.

Comment: I used this but had to skip the first row

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a fix, but more like a work around; I wrote an Excel Macro that appended a character (e.g. 'B') to the codes, then removed it when importing using Openrowset like:

```
select RIGHT([code], LEN([code])-1)
```