# Having problems reading an Excel spreadsheet using LinqToExcel, when dates are involved

Tags: c#, excel, date, linq-to-excel

I've got an Excel spreadsheet from our HR department that needs to be loaded into a database. One column has dates in it. I've searched here on SO and found 2 answers ([first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45314971/linqtoexcel-not-parsing-date/45356099#45356099) and the [second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102149/what-is-imex-in-the-oledb-connection-string#34247426)) which I thought might address my problem, but neither did.

First I tried doing a simple open of the spreadsheet:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(@"D:\Projects\LRAT\Example of SPO report 08-25-17 - Copy.xlsx");
```

I left the first row alone. In the class I defined to match the spreadsheet I defined the property for the dates originally like this:

```
[ExcelColumn("Date Current Step Filed")]
[DefaultValue("")]
public string DateStepsFiled { get; set; }
```

This worked, so longer as there were multiple dates in the column. But when there was just 1 date, LinqToExcel interpreted it with values like this: `39758`. Clearly, not at date. Or at least not one in mm/dd/yyyy format.

In reading what I did I got the impression that the first row, commonly the header row, influenced how LinqToExcel would process the spreadsheet. I don't quite get that because I thought that LinqToExcel ignored the first row anyway, but I decided to change the header for this column to today's date and I also changed the definition of the DateStepsFiled to this:

```
[ExcelColumn("Date Current Step Filed")]
[DefaultValue("")]
public DateTime[] DateStepsFiled { get; set; }
```

This was much worse, as LinqToExcel now defined all of the DateStepsFiled as null. So, how do I resolve this problem?

Comment: Never mind, I've discovered the problem. The spreadsheet is large, so I hadn't spent time looking throughout the rows of the spreadsheet. I just spent time at that and have discovered that the users, for whatever reason, entered lots of dates like `39758` and `39793` in a column that's meant to be for dates only. I've got to go back to them and ask them how in heck those values are to be interpreted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
public DateTime DateStepsFiled { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public DateTime[] DateStepsFiled { get; set; }
```

Comment: I thought it would have been DateTime[] because of values like this in the cell in the Excel spreadsheet:

8/15/2008
9/8/2008
11/13/2008