# Set no use headers and take the first row as a normal row in an Excel source file that have no headers

Tags: excel, ssis

I'm trying to get the first row from an Excel worksheet in a data flow task using SSIS.  My Excel source file doesn't have headers but SSIS always uses the first row as headers. How can I tell SSIS there are no headers in the Excel file?

Comment: IMEX=1 in the connection properties. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102149/what-is-imex-in-the-oledb-connection-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself

Right click on the Excel Connection Manager

[image]

And deselect this option

[image]