# Excel column data making alphabet values blank using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datatable

While uploading `Excel` there are values in columns in alphabets, so taking into `datatable` the values are getting blank.

below is the code which is making it blank.

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(fluploadData.FileName);
        // FileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
        string filenamewithoutrext = string.Empty;
        FileExt = Path.GetExtension(fluploadData.FileName).ToLower();
        if (Path.GetExtension(fluploadData.FileName).ToLower() != ".xls" &&
            Path.GetExtension(fluploadData.FileName).ToLower() != ".xlsx"
        )
        {

            Response.Write("Only .xls,.xlsx are allowed.!");
            return;
        }

        filenamewithoutrext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fluploadData.FileName).ToLower();

        string path = Server.MapPath("UploadData\\");
        string filename_ = filenamewithoutrext;

        //   DeleteDirectory(path);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))   // CHECK IF THE FOLDER EXISTS. IF NOT, CREATE A NEW FOLDER.
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
        }

        string fname;
        fname = path + filename_ + ".xls";

        fluploadData.SaveAs(fname);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["ExcelFilePath"] = fname;

        string conStr = "";
        System.Data.DataTable dtExcelRows = new System.Data.DataTable();

        switch (FileExt)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        conStr = String.Format(conStr, fname, "YES");

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connExcel = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(conStr);
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter oda = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;
        connExcel.Open();
        System.Data.DataTable dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        System.Data.DataTable dtExcelColumnsTable = connExcel.GetSchema("Columns");
        //string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Trim();  
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dtExcelRows);
        connExcel.Close();
```

Comment: `there are values in columns in alphabets` What does `in alphabets` mean?

Comment: @mjwills: values like `abcdef` ... ??

Comment: The short answer is that the Excel ODBC driver is guessing your data type incorrectly. I don't know how to fix that, other than don't use Excel.

Comment: @Magnetron: i didnt got you mate

Comment: I'd suggest SQL Server. Or Access.

Comment: Would it be possible to see your connection string? It may be possible to solve this issue by changing it (obviously blank any sensitive data).

Comment: @SBFrancies: here is the connection string `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}'` what should I change to ?  one more line after that. `conStr = String.Format(conStr, fname, "YES");`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely caused by mixed datatypes in a column. For example the first few rows have a number value so it is then presumed to be a column with a numeric type. When a non numeric value is encountered it can't be parsed and is ignored.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34247426/8532748) for some ways around this. They may include setting a value of `IMEX=1` in the connection string or treating the header row as data (`HDR=0`) - assuming your column names are non numeric.

You might also want to look into specific libraries which are designed for reading/writing Excel Documents, I have had good experiences with [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) but it only works for .xlsx files not .xls, [NPOI](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=npoi) which I haven't used can do both.

As others have mentioned if you are just using the Excel document as a datasource for the applications it may be better to look into an alternative solution such as SQL. If you have a requirement to process spreadsheets from third parties obviously that would not be an option.