# Why vba ado recordset does not get values from Excel table?

Tags: excel, vba, recordset

Good Day.

I have a problem with writing values from excel spreadsheet to ado recordset.

The spreadsheet "prox" contains the column of values such as:

- 958371030M
- 1200118
- 982140615D
- 1502680
- KB7W-62864

This column has text type.

I use following code:

```
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & wd & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;"";"

objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [prox$]", _
    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

Then recordset contains

- 958371030M
- 982140615D
- KB7W-62864

but numbers in text format are missed. On their places are empty spaces and

```
Debug.Print IsEmpty(objRecordset.Fields.Item(3).Value)
```

returns 'True' for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add the IMEX option

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & wd & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;"";"
```

For further details look at [this SO's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102149/what-is-imex-in-the-oledb-connection-string)