# SELECT and WHERE filters do not generate any output

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a set of codes to query dataset from a closed workbook. It works well with the sheet alone but just wouldn't work when I add in filters, Nothing will be imported to my destination file, no error message shown whatsoever.

Source Data (for illustration only):
[image]

```
Sub QueryA()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim wss As Worksheet

        Set wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Revenue")
        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

        Filename = C:\Users\PC\Documents\Revenue.xlsx
        wss.Cells.Clear
    
        conn.ConnectionString = _
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & Filename & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';"
        'IMEX=1 is used due to multiple data types

        conn.Open
        
        rst.Open _
            Source:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE YEARWEEK(Date) = YEARWEEK(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)", _
            ActiveConnection:=conn
            Debug.Print rst.Source
            wss.Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).CopyFromRecordset rst
            
        rst.Close
        conn.Close

        MsgBox "Data imported successfully."
End Sub
```

To test further, I also tried it out with other data column `Source:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]" WHERE Remarks = 'SMTH1'` `Source:="SELECT [Remarks] FROM [Sheet1$]"`

All these won't work.

The query **only** works well if `rst.source` is just like this:
`Source:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"` or `Source:="[Sheet1$]"`

Debug.Print prints the exact Query I wanted, but nothing is imported.
Is there something wrong with my codes here?

EDIT: Tried out Power Query

```
Sub PowerQueryA()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Revenue")
    
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim qName As String
    qName = "PowerQueryData"
    
    For Each qt In ws.QueryTables
        If qt.Name = qName Then
            qt.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next qt
    
    Dim LastMonday As Date, LastSunday As Date
    LastMonday = DateAdd("ww", -1, Now - (Weekday(Now, vbMonday) - 1))
    LastSunday = LastMonday + 6

    StartDate = Format(LastMonday, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    EndDate = Format(LastSunday, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    
    Dim connString As String
    connString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\PC\Documents\Book1 - Copy.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connString, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"), Sql:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Date >= StartDate AND Date <= EndDate")
    qt.Name = qName
    qt.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    qt.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: How about Power Query?

Comment: @taller Thanks for your suggestion. I added the codes in my original post. The same happened - nothing is pulled from source file. I had the `QueryTable.Refresh` in my code this time, it gives me the error message `Run-time error '1004': No value given for one or more required parameters.` EDIT: It still works when the query source stays at `SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]` or `[Sheet1$]`, but not with filters...

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the actual problem you're having. If you remove the unnecessary tags that shouldn't be in the title at all, the site rejects your title as being meaningless. Clearly, if your code worked the way you intended, you wouldn't be posting here. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user will know what it's about when skimming a list of search results. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change date format to `m/d/yyyy`
- `StartDate` and `EndDate` are varibles, use string concatation to bulid sql cmd.

Please try.

```vb
Sub PowerQueryA()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Revenue")
    
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim qName As String
    qName = "PowerQueryData"
    
    For Each qt In ws.QueryTables
        If qt.Name = qName Then
            qt.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next qt
    
    Dim LastMonday As Date, LastSunday As Date
    LastMonday = DateAdd("ww", -1, Now - (Weekday(Now, vbMonday) - 1))
    LastSunday = LastMonday + 6

    Dim StartDate As String, EndDate As String
    StartDate = Format(LastMonday, "m/d/yyyy")
    EndDate = Format(LastSunday, "m/d/yyyy")
    
    Dim connString As String, sSql as String
    sSql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Date>=#" & StartDate & "# AND Date<=#" & EndDate & "#"
    connString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\PC\Documents\Book1 - Copy.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connString, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"), Sql:=sSql)
    qt.Name = qName
    qt.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
    qt.Refresh
End Sub
```

---

- ADO demo with date filter (where clause)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ADO_Where_Demo()
    Dim sSrcFile As String
    Dim sSrcSht As String
    Dim oRSCon As Object, oRSData As Object
    Dim sDBCon As String, sSQL As String
    Dim i As Long
    sSrcFile = "d:\temp\ado.xlsx"
    ' with header starting in A1
    sSrcSht = "Sheet1"
    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        sDBCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & sSrcFile & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"
    Else
        sDBCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & sSrcFile & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
    End If
    sSQL = "SELECT * FROM [" & _
        sSrcSht$ & "$" & "] WHERE Date>#1/26/2024#;"
    Set oRSCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set oRSData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    oRSCon.Open sDBCon
    oRSData.Open sSQL, oRSCon, 0, 1, 1
    ' Write the output data to a new worksheet
    Worksheets.Add
    For i = 0 To oRSData.Fields.Count - 1
        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = oRSData.Fields(i).Name
    Next i
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset oRSData
    oRSData.Close: Set oRSData = Nothing
    oRSCon.Close: Set oRSCon = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This set of codes worked! But I'm clueless as to what was the underlying problem. Did I not use the right syntax for the parameters in Date column?

Comment: I've uploaded a code snippet about ADO. Hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for offering 2 different methods. My curiosity thickens. After I ran the ADO Demo codes on my data, I noticed the values Date Column shown in 5-digit Date value format. Then, I ran the code again, a new worksheet is created with the same output as previous, or so I thought) I went back to the sheet where the first output was generated, the 5-digit Date values in Date column auto-changed itself to the country-specific date format (in my case, dd/mm/yyyy). Did that happen to you as well?

Comment: When using ADO, don't tinker around with string formatting a date and hope that your underlying DB understands the string correctly. Use ADODB.Command and ADODB.Parameter instead.

Comment: @FunThomas Thanks for chipping in. RE: ADODB.Command and ADODB.Parameter, do you mean using IMEX=1 and HDR=0 mentioned in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10102149/what-is-imex-within-oledb-connection-strings/34247426#34247426 ?

Comment: All cells are in `General` format. Dates are showed as the country-specific date format. You can add a code line to format it as expected. btw, _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Parameters Collection (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Understood. Thanks. I'd like to dive deeper into the methods you use. Is there other advantages of using Power Query over ADO/ADODB for my case apart from better handling of the mixed data types? (I might consider using Power Query from now onwards.)